# How to generate multiple aar based on abi?

Tags: android, build.gradle, aar

I am using multiple .so files for different ABIs (armv7a, x86_64, x86). I am trying to generate aar file to wrap these. Currently, I am getting a single aar file for all abi, and size is very big of aar and then it'll create big sized apk. I need to have multile aar of the basis of abi declared in build.gradle. I tried split tag in build.gradle but it's not working.

Comment: I think that you don't really want different versions of the aar but rather different versions of the apk. "_I tried split tag in build.gradle but it's not working_" - do you mean you tried the split for the apk or the aar?

Comment: I am building aar using .so files, which I'll use further in separate app project. I want to make different versions of aar only on the basis of abi. I tried using a split tag in build.gradle.

Comment: @Rahul how were you able to generate 1 .aar file? In my case it's giving me option to choose active abi?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the cleanest way would be to have only 1 aar and then split your apks by architecture, however you can pack your native libraries in different versions of the aar with flavors.

In your library `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    ...

    flavorDimensions "abi"
    productFlavors {
        x86 {
            dimension "abi"
        }

        arm {
            dimension "abi"
        }
    }
}
```

Then create the flavor directories in your project:

```
project/
|-- mylibrary/
    |-- src/
        |-- main/ <- all your library code here
        |-- arm/
        |   |-- jniLibs/
        |       |-- armeabi/
        |           |-- libsomething.so
        |-- x86/
            |-- jniLibs/
                |-- x86/
                    |-- libsomething.so
```